# UICollectionViewCell changes cell contents when scrolling

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionView`.  I am using a `UIView` instead of a `UICollectionViewCell` as I'm wanting to use the `UIView` elsewhere.

The `UICollectionView` scrolls only horizontally and has 14 cells; each with the `UIView` as its contents.

Inside this `UIView` is another UICollectionView which houses a `UICollectionViewCell` which is just an image of a dice.

So:

1. Outer `UICollectionView` with `Cell`
2. The cell has a `UIView`
3. The UIView has a `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`
4. The `UICollectionViewCell` is just an `imageView` of a dice.

The problem I'm having is, when the `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally, the contents of the cell are changing when they should remain static; sometimes it randomly moves the contents, or completely removes the contents.

I'm not sure what is causing this to happen.

How can I ensure that upon scrolling that the `UICollectionView` keeps its contents intact?

Outer `UICollectionView`:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allLocos?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:OuterCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OuterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell

        if cell.cardView == nil {
            let arr = UINib(nibName: "CardView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
            let view = arr[0] as! CardView
            cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
            cell.cardView = view
        }

        if let locos = self.allLocos {
            let loco:EYLocomotive = locos[indexPath.row]
            print(indexPath.row, loco.name, loco.orders)
            cell.engineCardView?.setup(loco:loco)
        }


        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }
```

I think the issue is being caused by this line:

`cell.engineCardView?.setup(loco:loco)`

My `UIView` (The cardView) has this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var diceCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var dice:[Int] = [Int]()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setup(loco:EYLocomotive) {
        self.diceCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.diceCollectionView.dataSource = self
        self.diceCollectionView.allowsSelection = false
        self.diceCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        self.diceCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.diceCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.diceCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.diceCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "EYDiceCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "EYDiceCollectionViewCell")

// add dummy dice for testing purposes only
for var _ in 1...3 {
            let die = Die().roll
            dice.append(die)
        }

    }
```

The diceCollectionView is the holder of the Dice Imagery.

When we get to to the UICollectionViewDelegate; in the same file;

```
 // MARK: Collection View Delegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dice.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: EYDiceCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EYDiceCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EYDiceCollectionViewCell

        let dieValue = self.dice[indexPath.row] as Int

        let imageFile:String = "die-face-\(dieValue)"

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFile)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }
```

The UICollectionView works fine, the problem comes when I start scrolling horizontally out of the viewport and then scroll back.

- Contents of the cell change.
- Contents of the cell sometimes change to a different one to the one I'm expecting
- Contents of the cell sometimes disappear upon scrolling

What I'd like to know is how can I ensure the contents do not change?

With thanks

Comment: I am not sure if it would fix you problem, but when I need to create `UICollectionView` inside `UICollectionView` I set delegates and datasources to `UIViewController` and set tags for `UICollectionViews` (first cell in outer `UICollectionView` => tag 1 from inside `UICollectionView` and so on). so it is much easy to debug. And it works fine in my case (`UICollectionView` inside `UITableView`). I can provide code if you are interested.

Comment: I will give it a go.  I understand that it if I setup the delegates and data sources outside of the collection view I am in it might work.  I think the problem is that when the cell is being redrawn and each time it calls the setup function I wrote; which seems to remove the contents.   I will try your idea out

Comment: I decided just to use a collection of image views and hide/show them as I need them; its just quicker for me to do it this way and I am more interested in getting the project done than getting it right